# Correlation between sex and achievement

Tags: cognitive-psychology, personality, motivation, sexuality

I heard an anecdotal opinion that according to Sigmund Freud's psychoanalysis, people who don't fulfill themselves sexually tend to be more diligent. I would like to know; was any research conducted to confirm that statement?

By "don't fulfill themselves sexually" I mean that they are abstinent or unfulfilled

By "more diligent" I mean that they work harder or are more determined to **achieve** their goals.

All I could find to reference my question is defence mechanism described by Freud, called [sublimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublimation_%28psychology%29). I would like to know if any group-experiment based research can support this.

There is very similar question already on cogsci [here](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3849/can-motivation-for-sex-be-transformed-into-productive-motivation/3855#3855), which seems to provide conclusion that:

> The question "What is the effect of sexual abstinence on intellectual
>   and artistic achievment?" has specifically been answered by studies on
>   celibacy, which show either no or a negative effect (Baumeister, Dale,
>   & Sommer, 1998).

Comment: Any source for your claim? It seems a bit of a hearsay thing.

Comment: @Christiaan; Im aware that this may be a hearsay. If it will help; person who told me that, said it is related to Sigmund Freud's psychoanalysis.

Comment: Please don't reference psychoanalysis in anything scientific.

Comment: Because it's heresay, it's hard to discredit, so this question is in risk of being close as "primarily opinion-based". If you gave a reference to Freud or some other prominent psychoanalysis claiming this, it would be easier to find and analyze a response to answer your question.